# Backdrop filter doesn't apply if parent's opacity is less than 1

Tags: css

I have a container element that has variable opacity. Its child is supposed to cast a backdrop blur.

The issue is that the backdrop filter only applies when the parent's opacity is exactly 1. However, if I lower the opacity of the child itself, the backdrop filter stays.

Can anyone help me make this work properly?

I can't use background color to change the container's opacity.

```css
#container{
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  outline: 0.1px solid black;
}

#child{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px)
}
```

```html
<div>This should be blurred</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 80px">
<span>Parent opacity:</span><input type="range" id="parentRange" min="0" step="0.01" max="1" value="1"><span id="parentReadout">1</span><br>
<span>Child opacity:</span><input type="range" id="childRange" min="0" step="0.01" max="1" value="1"><span id="childReadout">1</span>
</div>

<script>
parentRange.oninput = (e) => {
  container.style.opacity = e.target.value
  parentReadout.textContent = e.target.value
}
childRange.oninput = (e) => {
  child.style.opacity = e.target.value
  childReadout.textContent = e.target.value
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have to get rid of opacity. That's your only way. If you cannot then I think it's impossible

Comment: `backdrop-filter` supports an `opacity()` function that you may be able to use to produce the same effect.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<br>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-br-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob Thanks! I'm coming fresh off of JSX to ask this, hence the mistake ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the [specification](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects-2/#backdrop-root) it's indeed not possible to do what I want without some yet unknown trickery.

I quoted the two key sections below, but the main idea is that the elements the filter are applied to are the ones between the backdrop root and the element with the backdrop-filter. The backdrop root is the nearest ancestor that fits at least one of a group of criteria, one of which is having an opacity < 1.

So in the scenario above, the parent becomes the backdrop root, and the **blur is only applied to elements between it and the child.**

The Spec:

> The Backdrop Root Image for an element E is the final image that would
> be produced by the following steps:
>
> Start at the **Backdrop Root element** that is the nearest ancestor of E.
>
> **Paint all content, in painting order, **between (and including) the
> ancestor Backdrop Root element and element E**.**
>
> Flatten the painted content into a 2D screen-space buffer.
>
> Transform the border box of element E to 2D screen-space, and clip the
> final painted output to this border quad.

And:

> A **Backdrop Root** is formed, anywhere in the document, by an element in
> any of the following scenarios. See § 3.2 Backdrop Root Triggers for
> more details on each:
>
> The root element of the document (HTML).
>
> An element with a filter property other than "none".
>
> **An element with an opacity value less than 1.**
>
> An element with mask, mask-image, mask-border, or clip-path properties
> with values other than “none”.
>
> An element with a backdrop-filter value other than "none".
>
> An element with a mix-blend-mode value other than "normal".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works. But adding background makes it works as expected. I changed html, because background overlaps the text.

I accidentally found this solution after trying to fix this problem in my project for several hours. I just needed the page to appear smoothly, from 0 opacity to 1. I already redid it so that the page was initially not transparent, and a background with biggest z-index was initially added on top of it with a transparency animation from 1 to 0 and then totally removed. It might be the solution because I'm still not sure if the background solves all problems. For example, here is some very strange border behavior on the middle element:

https://codepen.io/adic3x/pen/VwEbYgv

W/ background:

```js
parentRange.oninput = (e) => {
  container.style.opacity = e.target.value
  parentReadout.textContent = e.target.value
}
childRange.oninput = (e) => {
  child.style.opacity = e.target.value
  childReadout.textContent = e.target.value
}
```

```css
#container{
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  outline: 0.1px solid black;
  background: white;
}

#child{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  This should be blurred
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 80px">
<span>Parent opacity:</span><input type="range" id="parentRange" min="0" step="0.01" max="1" value="1"><span id="parentReadout">1</span><br>
<span>Child opacity:</span><input type="range" id="childRange" min="0" step="0.01" max="1" value="1"><span id="childReadout">1</span>
</div>
```

W/o background:

```js
    parentRange.oninput = (e) => {
      container.style.opacity = e.target.value
      parentReadout.textContent = e.target.value
    }
    childRange.oninput = (e) => {
      child.style.opacity = e.target.value
      childReadout.textContent = e.target.value
    }
```

```css
    #container{
      opacity: 1;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      width: 200px;
      height: 80px;
      outline: 0.1px solid black;
      /*background: white;*/
    }

    #child{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      This should be blurred
      <div id="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 80px">
    <span>Parent opacity:</span><input type="range" id="parentRange" min="0" step="0.01" max="1" value="1"><span id="parentReadout">1</span><br>
    <span>Child opacity:</span><input type="range" id="childRange" min="0" step="0.01" max="1" value="1"><span id="childReadout">1</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's a solution to an interesting problem, which is why when container becomes the backdrop root, since its opacity is less than 1, does its content not get included in the backdrop image. With a fully opaque background image, it does. It makes sense following the logic described in the spec but its not explicitly stated in it, only that the backdrop root element gets drawn inclusively. While this fixes the example I included, the question turned out to be more about the moving backdrop root. For example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p405j23z/1/),the background only blurs if the parent's opaque

Answer (score 0):

```css
backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
transform: translateZ(0);
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

`transform` and `backface-visibility` solve it for me because it creates a new backdrop root.